# Why does constrained return type require explicit cast?

Tags: c#, generics, polymorphism

Why does a method like this require the return type to be explicitly cast?

```
    public T Test<T> ()
        where T : Response
    {
        var ret = new Response ();

        return ret; // Explicit cast needed here
    }
```

The constraint explicitly states that T is Response or a child of it, so return type polymorphism should allow this without casting, or so I thought.

Adding `as T` allows compilation to pass.

Comment: Note that a cast will fail at runtime unless `T` _is_ `Response` and not a subtype.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the return value it is irrelevant whether `T` is of type `Response`. You need to return something of type `T`.

Think of a type `DerivedFromResponse`. Using your method `Test<DerivedFromResponse>`() would return `null` with the cast and would not work without it as you can't cast `Response` into `DerivedFromResponse` (only vice versa is possible).

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 5):

`T` is a subclass of `Response`, meaning every `T` is a `Response` but not every `Response` is a `T`. This is why you need an explicit cast.